# Rescale data to be sinuosoidal

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, rescale

I have some time series data I'm looking at in Python that I know should follow a sine<sup>2</sup>  function, but for various reasons doesn't quite fit it.  I'm taking an FFT of it and it has a fairly broad frequency spread, when it should be a very narrow single frequency. However, the errors causing this are quite consistent--if I take data again it matches very closely to the previous data set and gives a very similar FFT.

So I've been trying to come up with a way I can rescale the time axis of the data so that it is at a single frequency, and then apply this same rescaling to future data I collect. I've tried various filtering techniques to smooth the data or to cut frequencies from the FFT without much luck. I've also tried fitting a frequency varying sine<sup>2</sup>  to the data, but haven't been able to get a good fit (if I was able to, I would use the frequency vs time function to rescale the time axis of the original data so that it has a constant frequency and then apply the same rescaling to any new data I collect).

Here's a [small sample of the data I'm looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8td.png) (the full data goes for a few hundred cycles). And the [resulting FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CkJY.png) of the full data

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To get to a single frequency, it looks like you would need a non-linear transformation of the time access.   At that point I would (encourage you to) ask how the time access is recorded, and why you might expect non-linearities?  But also: the small but rather clear beating in the signal indicates that there really are more than 1 frequency that even a non-linear change in the time access would not be able to erase.   Are you sure this signal should have a very narrow frequency range?  It sure doesn't look that way.

Comment: This signal is made from a laser in an interferometer--the laser is split into two beams and recombined where they will interfere with each other. For simplicity of the problem, I said they this signal varies in time, but more it may be more accurate to say it varies in space. The nonliearities come from the fact that I can't translate the beam at a perfectly constant velocity--if I could though, the signal would certainly be a near perfect sine wave--this is fundamental to the laser. The beat frequency is due to misalignment and is unimportant--it should just show up as low frequency noise

Comment: I see that the amplitude of the signal varies smoothly.  Is it possible to use the amplitude information to derive the time axis rescaling?

Comment: Classically, and assuming you're well below the Nyquist frequency (your data looks like it is) a beat is due to two dominant frequencies that are close to one another (as with a whistle or two slightly-out-of-tune pitches).

Comment: @MNewville is right. Looking at the time data already I immediately thought there is a beating and that is what your fft shows. This is not low frequency noise.

Comment: Is there more than one laser frequency resulting in two ore more interference patterns on top of each other?